# Ads failed to load while using banner test ads

Tags: flutter, admob

Error Message:

Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))

I am getting this error while using banner test ads. I am using emulator and tested it on real device but no luck.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there was a problem with my AdMob account. An Ad limit was placed on my account and new accounts take some time before they can be used for ad services.

Comment: but what if I don't have an AdMob account and still have the same issue you had. any idea? I'm getting this error on all my ads in the app no ads showing no banner or interstitial.

Comment: You need to have an AdMob account to have this problem

Answer (score 2):

Did you add this line

```
void main() {

      runApp(MyApp());

      MobileAds.instance.initialize(); // here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying actually there was a problem with my AdMob account. An Ad limit was placed on my account and new accounts take some time before they can be used for ad services.